# Drupal 8 jQuery overrides frontend jQuery Version

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-8

One thing up front: I'm new to Drupal 8 so I'm sorry if that's a noob question.

**TL;DR Is there a way to separate jQuery Backend Scripts from custom jQuery Frontend Scripts?**

We bought a large template set which uses jQuery **1.x**. When implementing it in Drupal, Drupal loads up jQuery **2.x** for its backend and we get several error messages when logged in. So I tried to find a way to make Drupal use it's own namespace for it's backend scripts, but couldn't find a way to separate it from the frontend. Strangely the bought template set uses `jQuery` and `$` for it's functions, which is horrible! But it has 100+ js files that would have to be edited to make it equally.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `href` in `<link />` to make sure that the correct jQuery version is loaded.

But it depends on which jQuery version the theme is running.

For example if it is below 1.6 version:

```
$("link[href='http://jquery2.x.version.com']").attr('href', 'http://jquery1.x.version.com');
```

if it is above 1.6 version:

```
$("link[href='http://jquery2.x.version.com']").prop('href', 'http://jquery1.x.version.com');
```

Comment: the theme uses a bundled js file. it includes a lot of libraries and its custom code :(

Comment: plus: the custom functions need jQuery 1.x while drupal loads 2.x and uses it for its inline editing stuff. so in the end i will need **BOTH** jQuery versions.

Comment: Do you have a different link in the browser when you are logged into the admin dashboard?

Comment: It has been a long time since I've worked in Drupal. Isn't the admin dashboard on site.com/admin ??

Comment: no. you log into /user and then you're able to edit the page inline while browse in it